# jQuery: show selected text in the alert box upon Ctrl+a

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, key

With jQuery library, what's the best way to show alert with text selected on **Ctrl+a** keys clicked, if the text selected is a part of the text inside of `<div id="mydiv"></div>`? We don't care about Ctrl+a clicked, if the selected text is not inside `<div id="mydiv"></div>` or the text was not selected).

Comment: You could write a function that checks what is selected inside your mydiv element when a user presses CTRL+A using $(document).keydown(function(e){ if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 65) {} });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming, since `CTRL+A` is the universal shortcut for "select all" that you have some sort of text input or textarea inside your div to select text from. Otherwise, a CTRL+A is just going to select the entire page.

That being said, your question is a pretty straightforward use of the jQuery [onclick event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#myDiv').on('keyup', function (event) {
    if(event.ctrlKey) {
        if(event.keyCode == 65) {
            alert('You pressed CTRL+A');
        }
    }
});
```